# How To Handle 100's Scheduled Tasks Using ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, scheduled-tasks

I’m looking for advice on the most efficient and robust way to handle quite a large amount (100 to 300) of Scheduled tasks in an ASP.NET MVC 3 app.

Basically users can create an account, and can create multiple tasks that will run once a week or day at a specified time.  What the task is doing is irrelevant at the moment, but let’s just say for arguments sake it’s a scheduled tweet system.

Each of these tasks will be stored in the DB, but there could be dozens or hundreds all firing at the same time and throughout a day.

In the past I have used ‘Task Scheduler’ on the server to trigger tasks in a consistent and robust way when I have had say 5 to 10 tasks running, but now it’s going to move into the 100’s I’m looking for some solid advice on how to handle this kind of system, just using ASP.NET MVC 3 as I can’t rely on the task scheduler anymore.
Any comments and advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best is to create a windows service which will handle this. In this way it's independent of the web application (which is mainly a user interface after all).

If you're on a shared host (so you don't have access to setup windows services) then everything scheduler related (using a library like quartz.net or a custom solution) I think it's best to be wrapped in a singleton instance, probably stored in a static variable.